# How to change from basic DAO to Repository interface with Spring and Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple app that connects to MySQL database and gets all records from given table. It all works fine if I use simple DAO class that is then injected to Service class. But I wanted to replace it with interface that extends CrudRepository. To do that i created this interface:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>
{
    User save(User user);

    List<User> save(Iterable<? extends User> iterable);

    User findOne(Long aLong);

    boolean exists(Long aLong);

    List<User> findAll();

    long count();

    void delete(Long aLong);

    void delete(User user);

    void delete(Iterable<? extends User> iterable);

    void deleteAll();
}
```

I also changed my Context file to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd">

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
          class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="classpath:database.properties">
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.jnowacki.*" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.jnowacki.dictApp.repository"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.jnowacki.dictApp.service"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

</beans>
```

Interface is injected in Service class with @Autowired.
After trying to run this I get error: Failed to load ApplicationContext
it seems that there is something wrong with my xml namespaces or something, but it seems following all the examples I found online. There is full stack trace:

```
/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7537 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/opt/Intellij/idea-IU-143.1184.17/bin -Didea.junit.sm_runner -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/Intellij/idea-IU-143.1184.17/lib/idea_rt.jar:/opt/Intellij/idea-IU-143.1184.17/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/jce.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/resources.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/target/test-classes:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/target/classes:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/lib/servlet-api.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/lib/jsp-api.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-aspects-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-context-support-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-aop-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-instrument-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-instrument-tomcat-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-jms-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-expression-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-messaging-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-jdbc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-oxm-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-orm-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-tx-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-test-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-ws.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-security-acl-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-security-aspects-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-security-cas-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-security-ldap-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-security-remoting-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-security-crypto-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-security-taglibs-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-security-openid-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-webmvc-portlet-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-websocket-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-data-commons-core-1.1.0.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/spring-data-jpa-1.3.3.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/jnowacki/dict_app/lib/hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:/home/jnowacki/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:/home/jnowacki/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar:/home/jnowacki/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 com.jnowacki.dictApp.repository.UserRepositoryTest
Jul 19, 2016 4:32:54 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper getDefaultTestExecutionListenerClassNames
INFO: Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
Jul 19, 2016 4:32:54 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper getTestExecutionListeners
INFO: Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@6155b814, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@42a85af8, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@3aec71f8, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@792e6f00, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@5779a727, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@73cd1e4e]
Jul 19, 2016 4:32:54 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@3aec71f8] to prepare test instance [com.jnowacki.dictApp.repository.UserRepositoryTest@222661f8]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 36 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd; lineNumber: 36; columnNumber: 63; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:auditing-attributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:257)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd; lineNumber: 36; columnNumber: 63; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:auditing-attributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4162)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4145)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1741)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAttributeGroupTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDAttributeGroupTraverser.java:80)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAbstractTraverser.traverseAttrsAndAttrGrps(XSDAbstractTraverser.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.processComplexContent(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:1122)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexTypeDecl(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:335)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:164)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(XSDElementTraverser.java:392)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDElementTraverser.java:242)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(XSDHandler.java:1433)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:630)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:617)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2453)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1772)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:766)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:356)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 41 more


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 36 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd; lineNumber: 36; columnNumber: 63; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:auditing-attributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:257)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd; lineNumber: 36; columnNumber: 63; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:auditing-attributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4162)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4145)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1741)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAttributeGroupTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDAttributeGroupTraverser.java:80)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAbstractTraverser.traverseAttrsAndAttrGrps(XSDAbstractTraverser.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.processComplexContent(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:1122)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexTypeDecl(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:335)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:164)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(XSDElementTraverser.java:392)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDElementTraverser.java:242)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(XSDHandler.java:1433)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:630)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:617)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2453)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1772)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:766)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:356)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 41 more

Jul 19, 2016 4:32:54 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]

Process finished with exit code 255
```

I have been trying to overcome this for a few hours, will be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is a dependency mismatch - your versions of Spring and Spring Data don't properly match, you should use Spring's BOM in order to be sure that your versions are mutually compatible.

Add this to your POM file (I'm guessing you're using Maven):

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>__appropriate Spring version__</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

However, you'll also need to use the proper XSDs in your context.xml file, my suggestion would be to remove the versions from XSD links (user spring-jpa.xsd instead of spring-jpa-1.0.xsd).

Another issue that you're likely experience once you solve this one is - missing JPA configuration. Spring Data can be made to work with Hibernate, yes, but only through JPA, and you are using raw Hibernate support.

You can find out more about setting up Spring Data JPA by reading through [this Spring Data JPA tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html).

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Up to this point I imported necessary libs with Intellij (using hiberante and spring integration). After your reply I noticed they are really old. I will delete them and add dependencies in pom.xml. I am getting little confused with JPA in Spring and Hiberante and I need to read a little more on the topic. I got lost what uses what :) Anyway, thanks for a hint!

Comment: I think you meant something like it is explained here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html
when talking about jpa configuration?

Comment: No, I think that Spring Data reference that I shared was more pertinent, since you are attempting to work with Spring Data JPA; you'd have to try it yourself (I'm AFK at the moment) but I think the only thing you'd need to change is to replace the sessionFactory bean with an appropriate EntityManagerFactory and also replace HibernateTransactionManager with a JpaTransactionManager

Comment: Just managed to get it working, thank you! Used this example, by your latest reply I assume that was what you were meaning:
http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-hibernate-jpa.jsp
Now I need to check out why this is different from my previous implementation and what persistence.xml does. Thanks for help, I got really tangled around all these concepts.

Comment: That's it, partly - the only difference is that the example does not use Spring Data JPA but uses Spring ORM for JPA.